# sql server management studio problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

hello friend on w7 i configured my sql sever and ssms but while going through ssms it's producing following error...please resolve my problem.

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management
>   Studio Express
>
> The database model is not accessible.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ObjectExplorer)

Comment: Is it shown when you try to connect to database?

Comment: when i try to attach database it gives the following error

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.SmoEnum)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Comment: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

The server principal "Rupesh-PC\Rupesh" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.2047&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=916&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't have permissions.
May be it will help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/8b0ba6de-2cb2-4378-aa90-3f5a6551a734